# Checkbox change other checkbox statement

Tags: c++, qt

I need to connect some Checkboxes, so when I click one it becomes checked and other become unchecked. My code right now looks like this.

Connect in class constructor:

```
connect(cb_thickness1,SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)),this,SLOT(cb_thickness1_isChecked()));
connect(cb_thickness2,SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)),this,SLOT(cb_thickness2_isChecked()));
connect(cb_thickness3,SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)),this,SLOT(cb_thickness3_isChecked()));
```

and slots

```
void MainWind::cb_thickness1_isChecked()
{
    if(cb_thickness2->isChecked())
        cb_thickness2->setChecked(false);
    if(cb_thickness3->isChecked())
        cb_thickness3->setChecked(false);
}
void MainWind::cb_thickness2_isChecked()
{
    if(cb_thickness1->isChecked())
        cb_thickness1->setChecked(false);
    if(cb_thickness3->isChecked())
        cb_thickness3->setChecked(false);

}
void MainWind::cb_thickness3_isChecked()
{
    if(cb_thickness1->isChecked())
        cb_thickness1->setChecked(false);
    if(cb_thickness2->isChecked())
        cb_thickness2->setChecked(false);

}
```

Code doesn't work as expected. When I click to any ChBx first time, everything is OK, but when I click to other next time it only uncheck previous and does nothing with itself. Only on second click it become chekced.

Also I found one more bug, when I check to ChBox, and then uncheck it by clicking it againg, I can check 2 ChBxes. [pic 2]

[image: Form]
[image: Two ChBx checked]

Comment: why not using [radio button](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qradiobutton.html) which are design for kind of use ?

Comment: I dodn't try use radio button, but it's good idea, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Radio button is a great idea.

But if you really want to use check box, you can explicitly set `cb_thickness1` checked in `cb_thickness1_isChecked()`, and do the same for other two check boxes.

```
void MainWind::cb_thickness1_isChecked()
{
    cb_thickness1->setChecked(true);
    cb_thickness2->setChecked(false);
    cb_thickness3->setChecked(false);
}
void MainWind::cb_thickness2_isChecked()
{
    cb_thickness1->setChecked(false);
    cb_thickness2->setChecked(true);
    cb_thickness3->setChecked(false);
}
void MainWind::cb_thickness3_isChecked()
{
    cb_thickness1->setChecked(false);
    cb_thickness2->setChecked(false);
    cb_thickness3->setChecked(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to derive a class from QCheckBox (lets call it **CustomCheckBox**) and add a **signal**, **private slot** and **public slot**

signal:

```
void enabled();
```

private slot:

```
void CustomCheckBox::checkEnable(bool state)
{
    if(state)
    {
        emit enabled();
    }
}
```

public slot:

```
void CustomCheckBox::uncheck()
{
    setChecked(false);
}
```

In the constructor add:

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(checkEnable(bool)));
```

This way you can use simple connects.

```
CustomCheckBox *box1 = new CustomCheckBox();
CustomCheckBox *box2 = new CustomCheckBox();

connect(box1,SIGNAL(enabled()),box2,SLOT(uncheck()));
```

Feel free to improve this answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the state of the button is checked in the slot and then deactivate the other checkboxes like you already did.  You can use the parameter of the stateChanged method by passing it to the slots.

Here is code that works:
Variant I:

```
connect(ui->checkBoxA, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(checkBoxAChanged(int)));
connect(ui->checkBoxB, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(checkBoxBChanged(int)));
connect(ui->checkBoxC, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(checkBoxCChanged(int)));

void MainWindow::checkBoxAChanged(int state)
{
if (state == Qt::Checked) {
    ui->checkBoxB->setChecked(false);
    ui->checkBoxC->setChecked(false);
}
}

void MainWindow::checkBoxBChanged(int state)
{
if (state == Qt::Checked) {
    ui->checkBoxA->setChecked(false);
    ui->checkBoxC->setChecked(false);
}
}

void MainWindow::checkBoxCChanged(int state)
{
if (state == Qt::Checked) {
    ui->checkBoxB->setChecked(false);
    ui->checkBoxA->setChecked(false);
}
}
```

Variant II:

```
connect(ui->checkBoxA, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(checkBoxAClicked(bool)));
connect(ui->checkBoxB, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(checkBoxBClicked(bool)));
connect(ui->checkBoxC, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(checkBoxCClicked(bool)));

void MainWindow::checkBoxAClicked(bool val)
{
if (val == true) {
    ui->checkBoxB->setChecked(false);
    ui->checkBoxC->setChecked(false);
}
}

void MainWindow::checkBoxBClicked(bool val)
{
if (val == true) {
    ui->checkBoxA->setChecked(false);
    ui->checkBoxC->setChecked(false);
}
}

void MainWindow::checkBoxCClicked(bool val)
{
if (val == true) {
    ui->checkBoxB->setChecked(false);
    ui->checkBoxA->setChecked(false);
}
}
```